# How should I avoid out of memory using nodejs?

Tags: node.js

```
var  pass = require('./pass.js');
var  fs   = require('fs');
var path  = "password.txt";
var name  ="admin";
var
  remaining = "",
  lineFeed = "\r\n",
  lineNr = 0;

var log = 
  fs.createReadStream(path, { encoding: 'utf-8' })
  .on('data', function (chunk) {
    // store the actual chunk into the remaining
    remaining = remaining.concat(chunk);

    // look that we have a linefeed
    var lastLineFeed = remaining.lastIndexOf(lineFeed);

    // if we don't have any we can continue the reading
    if (lastLineFeed === -1) return;

    var
      current = remaining.substring(0, lastLineFeed),
      lines = current.split(lineFeed);

    // store from the last linefeed or empty it out
    remaining = (lastLineFeed > remaining.length)
      ? remaining.substring(lastLineFeed + 1, remaining.length)
      : "";

    for (var i = 0, length = lines.length; i < length; i++) {
      // process the actual line
      var account={
        username:name,
        password:lines[i],
      };
      pass.test(account);
    }
  })
  .on('end', function (close) {
    // TODO I'm not sure this is needed, it depends on your data
    // process the reamining data if needed
    if (remaining.length > 0) {
        var account={
            username:name,
            password:remaining,
        };
         pass.test(account);
    };
  });
```

I tried to do something like test password of account "admin", *pass.test* is a function to test the password, I download a weak password dictionary with a large number of lines,so I search for way to read that many lines of weak password,but with code above, the lines array became too large ,and run out of memory,what should I do?

Comment: You should process each line as you read it, and not try to hold the whole thing in memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insofar as my limited understanding goes, you need to watch a 1GB limit, which I believe is imposed by the V8 engine, actually. ([Here's a link](http://blog.caustik.com/2012/04/11/escape-the-1-4gb-v8-heap-limit-in-node-js/), actually saying the limit is 1.4 GB, currently, and lists the different params used to change this manually.) Depending on where you host your node app(s), you can increase this limit, by a param set on the command line when node is started. Again, see the linked article for a few ways to do this.

Also, you might want to make sure that, whenever possible, you use buffers, instead of converting things like data streams (from a DB or other things, for instance) to arrays/whatever, as this will then load the entire dataset into memory. As long as it lives in a buffer, it doesn't contribute to the total memory footprint of your app.

And actually, one thing that doesn't make sense, and that seems to be *very* inefficient in your app, is that, on reading each chunk of data in, you then check your username against **EVERY** username you've amassed so far, in your lines array, instead of the **LAST** one. What your app should do is keep track of the last username and password combo you've read in, and then delete all data before this user, in your `remaining` variable, so you keep your memory down. And since it's not a hold all repository for every line of your password file anymore, you should probably retitle it something like `buffer` or something. This means that you'd remove your `for` loop, since you're already "looping" through the data in your password file, by reading it in, chunk by chunk.

Comment: How should I limited the buffer to load data, not load all in memory once?

Comment: I want to do something "bad" to enter my school website .I just found a weak password dictionary to try to get An admin authority . I'm not sure there password match the "admin" account.(I just knew "admin" is a valid account)

Comment: @ggaaooppeenngg See my most recent comments. Basically, your fundamental flaw is that you're looping through **every** username/password combo you've amassed so far **each** time you read in a chunk. Instead, you should just be grabbing the chunks as they come, and as soon as you have a new username/password combo read in, you should then `pass.test()` against it at that point, and clear everything before that from your `remaining` var.

Comment: @ggaaooppeenngg Um, if that's what you're using it for... you're not gonna get any more help from me.

Comment: I just did a try not real destroy.I got some ideas,but how large is the chunk? Is there some defenition about it? `remaining = remaining.substring(lastLineFeed + 1, remaining.length)` won't clear unneccesary remaining? I thought lines is decided by the size of chunk.

Comment: B I print the length of lines(5000+) and chunk(60000+). When event "data" happen there will be a new lines array declared, is the previous lines array still in memory?